# java: how to set a global thread-ID?

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j, distributed

Is there any possibility to set unique ID for a thread? In distributed system where threads are created on many different machines (e.g. by RMI)?

I need it to create log messages. From my research I know that it can be done using log4j mdc/ndc, but only in single thread. My problem is that ID has to be set when thread is created (to use the same ID for threads on different JVM but for the same request)

I am new to distributed systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a globally unique request id, you can use the prcoessAndName (see below) with a counter and pass this with your message/request and use this to set the thread name.

```
public void processRequest(String uniqueRequestId, args) {
    Thread t = Thread.currrentThread();
    String tName = t.getName();
    try {
        t.setName("Processing " + uniqueRequestId);
        // preform process request
    } finally {
        t.setName(tName);
    }
}
```

This way the thread's name will contain the request id regardless of which thread/machine it is run in.  If you include the thread's name in the logs, it will be included.

---

You can set the name of your thread using

```
String processAndHost = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()
```

You can append to this a descriptive name or counter.

This way all your thread names will be unique.

You can assume this name is globally unique provided, a) you have a unique hostname b) the process is not restarted so often there is a significant risk of two clients (at different times) with the same process id on the same host being a problem.

This can be combined with a locally unique id, to get a distributed unique id.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
    final String processName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        String name = processName+"-"+counter.getAndIncrement();
        return new Thread(r, name);
    }
});
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] - Hello World.");
            Thread.yield();
        }
    });
service.shutdown();
```

prints

```
[9480@myhost-0] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-3] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-2] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-1] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-5] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-4] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-6] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-7] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-0] - Hello World.
[9480@myhost-7] - Hello World.
```

Comment: @Perter Lawrey - Can we track request from the first to the last thread using this unique name?

Comment: He doesn't want them globally unique, Peter, he wants them global across distributed requests. Not an answer, sorry.

Comment: @trebuchet Lucky you. Hard to tell these days the ways the kids dress :-)

Comment: Generating a sufficiently unique id is the hard part, how you set it is relatively easy. (Added another example) An alternative is to use UUID, but I find it much harder to trace to its source. With process id and hostname, you can easily find the process which created the id if its still running.

Comment: @trebucket I have seen a trebucket fireball. An amazing thing to see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT5zU1QYlc4

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think that generating unique ID isn't the hardest part.  Passing it with message/request seems to be much more difficult. Any ideas how to do this painlessly? I mean without huge changes in the source code.

Comment: If you are writing the RPC/messaging library yourself, you can add this as a field and use it automatically.  If you are trying to use standard RMI, the only option to you is to add it as a field in an object, or an argument to the method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I use RMI. Adding a field/argument is a solution I needed I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can give threads a name (see the different constructors of class `java.lang.Thread`). You could make up a name for each thread which consists of for example the computer name plus a unique number.

If you're creating threads using for example an `ExecutorService`, then you could pass that `ExecutorService` your own implementation of `java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory` to make threads and set their name.

Comment: Does it mean that I can set a the same name for threadB which is created automatically on a different JVM by threadA ?

Comment: @trebuchet No, nothing he said implies that, or anything even close to it. He hasn't answered your actual question, and neither have several others.

Comment: @EJP Ok, I have some difficulties with understanding then. But is this possible to set ID in that way?

Answer (score 1):

Not without unacceptable thread-creation overheads there isn't.

You should be logging by request-ID or session ID, not some impossible-to-implement global threadID that doesn't even exist.

I think you need to do some research on clicktrack logging.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But can thread recognize which request created it? Or should request-IDs go with control flow? How to do that?

Comment: As soon as a request enters the system, you stuff it into the logging MDC. When the request is done, delete it from MDC. Then you don't have to fiddle with the thread IDs.

Comment: @A.H. That sounds great! But I am not sure if it can work when request goes through a lot of threads. I thought MDC can help only when one request=one thread. But if I am wrong, it can be great solution.

Comment: If the request really is handed over from thread to thread, then you really have a problem. Then each receiving thread must do the MDC setting. It all depends on your frameworks - is there some central place to do such cross cutting concerns savely or not - _we_ don't know.

Comment: @EJP I have begun my research. But when I tried to google "clicktrack logging" I didn't find anything helpful. Do you know any examples or tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a name for the thread but you cant set/change an ID of a thread
From java docs of Thread's getId method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()

"Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused."