# JAVA: How to set thread name (RMI)?

Tags: java, multithreading, distributed

After my research and discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664741/java-how-to-set-a-global-thread-id) I decided I need to set the same name for threads on different JVMs which belong to the same control flow in the distributed system. Threads are created e.g. by RMI. Is it possible to set name when thread is created in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic means to transfer this info from client-to-server.

It sounds like you want/need some sort of `Context` object set up on the client (per-thread?) and passed as a method argument to your RMI servers. That `Context` object could contain not just the thread-name, but perhaps also other info like the calling process pid etc.

You'd then have to use that `Context` object to set thread-names etc. accordingly via `Thread.setName()` once it's been passed across the wire. Going forwards, you could set up context-specific info in your logging framework using this (e.g. using Log4j [nested diagnostic contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html))

The use of aspects to automate this further is left as a further exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: I did a lot of research about log4j and mdc/ndc but unfortunately it cannot detect distributed thread. The point of my question was: how to set a unique name for every request, pass it with control flow and then use log4j adding this name to logs to finally gather them together and group by request-name.

Comment: Yes. You'd *have* to do some work on the server (receiving) side no matter what solution you choose. You *could* possibly automate this using aspects (AspectJ or similar) but that's another question!

Comment: Actually I did my research about AspectJ too :) My idea was to add logging in `@around` aspect as I need to measure the execution times. So is it possible to set thread name using aspects (one name for all threads connected to one request)? How to pass this name?

Comment: I will refer you to the above answer again. I think it contains all you need

Answer (score 0):

The Thread class has a static method to `setName(String)`. If you can have your threads, wherever they come from, running that method, you should be good to go. [These guys](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Change-thread-name-of-HTTP-worker-threads-at-Runtime-td2143050.html) had similar issues with Tomcat related threads.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question is more about passing name across JVMs without adding  a field in an object, or an argument to the every method connected with RMI, but I need to study this link more carefully .

Comment: It is not a static method. Obviously.